# Write a program that works out whether if a given number is an odd or even number

Tags: python

New to coding. Learning Python. Trying to complete assignments but keep getting a syntax error on else. Don't know why.
Can you help?

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number % 2 == 0:
  print("This is an even number.")
  else:
    print("This is an odd number.")
```

Comment: Please show what syntax error you get.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the indent before else. Change to

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number % 2 == 0:
  print("This is an even number.")
else:
  print("This is an odd number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `if` and `else` on the same identation level.

```py
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number % 2 == 0:
  print("This is an even number.")
else:
  print("This is an odd number.")
```